# Conditions for using FIlestream

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, sqlfilestream

I want to rent a dedicated Server for my company with the newest Microsoft SQL-Server on it and I want to use filestream to store some PDF Files within the SQL Server. I have read "Windows only" on the official Microsoft site and I am wondering if this means that the Server musnt run on a Linux Server or does this mean that the SQL Server needs to run on a local Windows machine and not Windows Server?

I just want to confirm my initial conclusion that the server I want to rent must be a Windows Server Running-SQL Server on it since I am not completely sure how this works, I have never done this.

Comment: "Windows only" means just that: Windows only. SQL Server does not care if it's running on a client or server edition of Windows, when it's running on Windows. It's just as capable on either. (Server editions come with less restrictions on what hardware they support, though, and that obviously does influence what SQL Server can do.) At present, `FILESTREAM` isn't supported on Linux yet, that's all.

Comment: Thank you, that was exacly the answer I was looking for